# issue with passing return value from a task as an argument to another task

Tags: airflow

i've a task that returns a tuple. passing one element of that tuple to another task is not working. i can pass the entire tuple, but not an element from the return value:

```py
    from airflow.decorators import dag, task
    from pendulum import datetime
    
    
    @task
    def create():
        return 1, 2
    
    
    @task
    def consume(one):
        print('arg is', one)
    
    
    @dag(
        schedule_interval='@once',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 4, 10),
    )
    def test_dag():
        out = create()
        consume(out[0])  # does not work: the task gets None as argument
        consume(out)     # this works
    
    dag = test_dag()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within [TaskFlow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/taskflow.html?highlight=xcomarg) the object returned from a TaskFlow function is actually an `XComArg`.  These `XComArgs` are abstractions over the classic `task_instance.xcom_pull(...)` retrieval of `XComs`.  Additionally `XComArg` objects [implement `__getitem__`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/xcom_arg.html#XComArg.__getitem__) for specifying an `XCom` key other than "return_value" (which is the default).

So what's going on in the case of using `consume(out[0])` is that Airflow is leveraging an `XComArg` object to retrieve an `XCom` with a key of 0 *not* retrieving the output from `create()` and *then* the first item. What's going on behind the scenes is `task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="create", key=0)`.

Yes, this is unexpected in a way and it's not *quite* inline with the classic `xcom_pull()` approach. [This issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16618) has been opened to try and achieve feature parity.

In the meantime, you can of course access the whole `XComArg` like you show by just using `consume(out)` or you can update the TaskFlow function to return a dictionary and use `multiple_outputs` to have each key/value pair serialized as their own `XComs`.

For example:

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@task(multiple_outputs=True)
def create():
    return {"one": 1, "two": 2}


@task
def consume(arg):
    print('arg is', arg)


@dag(
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 4, 10),
)
def test_dag():
    out = create()
    consume(out["one"])

dag = test_dag()
```

Separate XComs created from the `create` task:
[image: Separate XComs created from the create task]

`consume` task log:
[image]

Side note: `multiple_outputs` can also be inferred if the TaskFlow function has a dictionary return type annotation too. This will set `multiple_outputs=True` based on the return annotation:

```py
from typing import Dict

@task
def create() -> Dict[str, int]:
    return {"one": 1, "two": 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to return a dict, you can instead pass the `create` task's result directly to the `consume` task.

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from pendulum import datetime
    
@dag(
  schedule_interval='@once',
  start_date=datetime(2022, 4, 10),
)
def test_dag():
  @task
  def create():
    # log: INFO - Done. Returned value was: (1, 2)
    return 1, 2
    
  @task
  def consume(my_tuple):
    # log: INFO - 1
    print(my_tuple[0]) 

  consume(create())


dag = test_dag()
```

The `@task`s work when defined in the dag like the above, or outside it as in your original example.