# Taskflow API not updating XCOMS

Tags: airflow

Trying the Taskflow API and trying to print values returned via XCOM's, however, unable to do so. Could anyone let me know where am I going wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.decorators import dag, task

default_args = {
    'owner': 'ashish',
    'retries': '2',
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}


@dag(dag_id='DAG_with_TaskFlow_API',
     default_args=default_args,
     description='Example for Task Flow API',
     start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 30, 2),
     schedule_interval='@daily')
def hello():

    # Setting the value normally
    @task()
    def get_name():
        return 'Ashish'

    # Passing multiple values
    @task()
    def get_fullname(multiple_outputs=True):
        return {'firstname': 'Ashish', 'lastname': 'Inamdar'}

    @task()
    def greet(name):
        print(f"Hello {name}")

    @task()
    def greet_multiple(firstname, lastname):
        print(f"Hi {firstname} {lastname}")

    name = get_name()
    greet(name=name)

    fullname_dict = get_fullname()
    greet_multiple(fullname_dict['firstname'], fullname_dict['lastname'])


taskflow_api_dag = hello()
```

I have read and tried the same approach shown in an another answer by Josh Fell cited on the link [issue with passing return value from a task as an argument to another task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72030438/issue-with-passing-return-value-from-a-task-as-an-argument-to-another-task/72059563#72059563)

Below are the airflow logs for the task:

```
3a4feea079c
*** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=DAG_with_TaskFlow_API/run_id=manual__2023-09-10T05:23:33.215377+00:00/task_id=greet_multiple/attempt=3.log
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1159} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: DAG_with_TaskFlow_API.greet_multiple manual__2023-09-10T05:23:33.215377+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1159} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: DAG_with_TaskFlow_API.greet_multiple manual__2023-09-10T05:23:33.215377+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1361} INFO - Starting attempt 3 of 3
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1382} INFO - Executing <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): greet_multiple> on 2023-09-10 05:23:33.215377+00:00
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 16082 to run task
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'DAG_with_TaskFlow_API', 'greet_multiple', 'manual__2023-09-10T05:23:33.215377+00:00', '--job-id', '162', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/task_with_taskflow_api.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmptyfhicx8']
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 162: Subtask greet_multiple
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {task_command.py:415} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: DAG_with_TaskFlow_API.greet_multiple manual__2023-09-10T05:23:33.215377+00:00 [running]> on host f3a4feea079c
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {abstractoperator.py:696} ERROR - Exception rendering Jinja template for task 'greet_multiple', field 'op_args'. Template: (XComArg(<Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): get_fullname>, 'firstname'), XComArg(<Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): get_fullname>, 'lastname'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 688, in _do_render_template_fields
    rendered_content = self.render_template(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/template/templater.py", line 162, in render_template
    return tuple(self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/template/templater.py", line 162, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/template/templater.py", line 158, in render_template
    return value.resolve(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom_arg.py", line 431, in resolve
    raise XComNotFound(ti.dag_id, task_id, self.key)
airflow.exceptions.XComNotFound: XComArg result from get_fullname at DAG_with_TaskFlow_API with key="firstname" is not found!
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1943} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1518, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context, test_mode, session=session)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1646, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    task_orig = self.render_templates(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2291, in render_templates
    original_task.render_template_fields(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1244, in render_template_fields
    self._do_render_template_fields(self, self.template_fields, context, jinja_env, set())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/abstractoperator.py", line 688, in _do_render_template_fields
    rendered_content = self.render_template(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/template/templater.py", line 162, in render_template
    return tuple(self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/template/templater.py", line 162, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(self.render_template(element, context, jinja_env, oids) for element in value)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/template/templater.py", line 158, in render_template
    return value.resolve(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom_arg.py", line 431, in resolve
    raise XComNotFound(ti.dag_id, task_id, self.key)
airflow.exceptions.XComNotFound: XComArg result from get_fullname at DAG_with_TaskFlow_API with key="firstname" is not found!
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1400} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=DAG_with_TaskFlow_API, task_id=greet_multiple, execution_date=20230910T052333, start_date=20230910T052746, end_date=20230910T052746
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 162 for task greet_multiple (XComArg result from get_fullname at DAG_with_TaskFlow_API with key="firstname" is not found!; 16082)
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:228} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-09-10, 05:27:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2784} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: [Update] I even tried replacing ```greet_multiple(fullname_dict['firstname'], fullname_dict['lastname'])``` with ```greet_multiple(firstname=fullname_dict['firstname'], lastname=fullname_dict['lastname'])```, still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiple_outputs` is a parameter on the underlying operator and not an input to the decorated function; think of it like adding `retries`, `queue`, `pool`, and other "general" BaseOperator-related parameters. There are a few examples of explicitly passing a `multiple_outputs` value in the [TaskFlow API tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html) too.

So, moving `multiple_outputs=True` to the `@task` decorator itself will solve the XCom retrieval.

```py
# Passing multiple values
@task(multiple_outputs=True)
def get_fullname():
    return {'firstname': 'Ashish', 'lastname': 'Inamdar'}
```

Airflow will also [*infer* a `multiple_outputs` value](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#multiple-outputs-inference) if the return annotation of the decorated function is a dictionary.

Meaning this would also work:

```py
@task
def get_fullname() -> dict[str, str]:
    return {'firstname': 'Ashish', 'lastname': 'Inamdar'}
```

Comment: Thank you @Josh, this really helped. Thank you for the knowledge links too :)